# How to Set Value Column to value Rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table dbo.tbbuy like below:

[image]

I want to get result table like below:

[image]

Comment: Is there number Value columns known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your table has no ordering, so you can just use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select name, min(value) as value1, max(value) as value2
from t
group by name;
```

A more general approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

If you want the values in a particular order, then change the `order by` clause.